# Sci-fi novel about a war between humans and bipedal alien deer

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space-colonization

I read this maybe 30 years ago. but to be safe let's say somewhere between 1986 and 1995, but probably right in the middle of that span.

Science fiction paperback, average length. I don't recall anything about the cover.

There are two planets, neither one Earth, existing in the same solar system; one might have actually been the moon of the other.

One of the globes is filled with human colonists, the other with a race of bipedal deer-like creatures that are our equal in intelligence. They were covered in soft, close cropped fur and had antlers.  They may have been deer that were genetically modified with unexpected results, but don't quote me on that bit.

The two sides go to war. At some point the human protagonist becomes a POW and develops a quasi-friendship, or at least a mutual respect, with the warden. This was NOT a children's book; at one point a POW caught raping his fellow inmates is dispatched by the protagonist with the wardens approval.

At the end of the novel the humans nuke the deer world and end the war, reducing the other species to a nomadic pre-industrial existence.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/15jdbuw/scifi_book_about_a_war_with_a_race_of_bipedal/ - Don't forget to mention if you've posted this question elsewhere

Comment: What made the aliens "deer-like?"  Presumably they must have had hands instead of hooves, and if they're bipedal they wouldn't have a deer-like silhouette...  Did they have antlers?

Comment: I updated the post in response to these questions.  Thanks!